# Buttons remove of carousel elements [react-multi-carousel]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-multi-carousel

How do I remove the arrows in the react-multi-carousel?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Carousel
      swipeable={false} // Disable swipe to prevent arrows from showing
      draggable={false} // Disable dragging to prevent arrows from showing
      showDots={false} // Optionally, hide the dots navigation as well
      responsive={responsive}
      // Other settings and props for your carousel go here
    >
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        // Your slide item JSX goes here
      ))}
    </Carousel>
```